# asp.net controls for iPhone development

Tags: asp.net, iphone

The ASP.NET iPhone controls from [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioiPhone/) is an interesting idea. However $800 is beyond my budget. Is there anything similar in the open source/free/cheaper world?

Answer (score 0):

[jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) is a free JavaScript library for iPhone web dev. I would still recommend ComponentOne's iPhone controls since they have full server-side support. If all you need is client-side support then jQTouch might work though...